# Input 0 of layer sequential_43 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 32, 32, 100000)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

My error:

```
Input 0 of layer sequential_43 is incompatible with the layer: 
: expected min_ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (None, 32, 32, 100000)
```

The shapes of my input:

`samples.shape` gives `(32,32,32,100000)`

`labels.shape` gives `(100000,)`

The code I'm now trying to run is the following:

```
model = keras.models.Sequential()
layers = tf.keras.layers

model.add(layers.Conv3D(filters=5, kernel_size=(4,4,4), strides=2, activation='relu', input_shape=(8,32,32,32,1)))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(filters=5, kernel_size=(4,4,4), strides=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(filters=5, kernel_size=(4,4,4), strides=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(filters=5, kernel_size=(4,4,4), strides=1, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Conv3D(filters=5, kernel_size=(4,4,4), strides=2, activation='relu'))


model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='relu'))

model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),loss='mape',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=samples,y=labels,validation_split=0.1,epochs=1,shuffle=True,verbose=2)
```

Everywhere I look the syntax is (batchsize,dim1,dim2,dim3,dim4). I put batchsize to 8, the data as a 32x32x32 cube, and the colour to 1 dimension. Even if i remove the batchsize from the `input_shape` and add it to `model.fit` as `batch_size=8` it gives the same error. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in your question, the order of the dimensions is `(batchsize,dim1,dim2,dim3,dim4)`, so you need to reshape your `samples` array to match that order.

You can transpose your array to get the number of samples as the first dimension, and expand it to get the channel dimension (or colour, if I reuse your term)  to 1.

```
>>> samples.shape
TensorShape([32, 32, 32, 100000])
>>> samples = tf.expand_dims(tf.transpose(samples,[3,0,1,2]), axis=-1)
>>> samples.shape
TensorShape([100000, 32, 32, 32, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! A tip for future readers; numpy has equivalent functions and will not push these to your GPU and crash for big data structures.